# Unboxing the first element of an optional vector and box it again

Tags: c++

Consider this example.

```
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
    std::optional<std::string> name;
};

std::optional<std::vector<std::string>> makeNames() {
    return {{"adam", "eve"}};
}

Person makePerson() {
    auto names = makeNames();
    return {
        names ? std::make_optional(std::move((*names)[0])) : std::nullopt
    };
}
```

1. Are there any copies of strings (etc) made inside `makePerson`?
2. Is there a way to statically assert/enfore that an expression doesn't create a copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any copies of strings (etc) made inside makePerson?

No, `std::string`s are not copied. However `std::vector`s and `std::string`s are moved.

`std::string` is moved only in `std::make_optional` to emplace into the optional returned by the function. This is impossible to avoid, because `std::optional` embeds the value it holds in itself. If that is not desired `std::unique_ptr` can be used instead.

`std::string`s would be copied only if `std::vector` was copied, not if it is moved. `std::vector`'s move constructor will not move string elements either.

There are however string copy constructions in `makeNames`, because of the use of the `std::initializer_list` constructor which doesn't support move semantics. If you use `emplace_back` into the vector instead after a suitable `reserve`, then you can trade all copies/moves of strings in `makeNames` against one potentially-elided vector move construction.

Nothing in the above changes if a different element type instead of `std::string` is used.

> Is there a way to statically assert/enfore that an expression doesn't create a copy?

No, you can however wrap `std::string` in a class that is non-copyable and then see whether compilation will fail when using that wrapped string instead as element type.

Similarly you can wrap `std::vector` to make it non-copyable from which not copying the strings would follow.

You can also replace the allocator for `std::string` or `std::vector` and observe where memory for strings is allocated or string objects are constructed. You could forbid string copy construction in the vector allocator.

With the standard allocator you can also replace global `operator new`/`operator delete` and observe memory allocation there. However, the compiler is permitted to elide calls to them under certain circumstances if it can provide for memory in other ways.

If the strings are short enough for SSO to be used, then observing memory allocations won't help either.

Comment: @user3612643 Well, the answer will be exactly the same. Just replace `std::string` with `char`.

Comment: @user3612643 Also, I fixed a mistake in my answer. There is of course an element type move for the construction of the returned optional. That's impossible to avoid, because `std::optional` must embed the object in itself.

Comment: @user3612643 Also note that in `makeNames` there _are_ string copies, see edit again.

Comment: @user17732522 left no part unexplained. thanks

Comment: After the `std::string` was moved into the optional. What's then happening when it is used to initialise the `Person` struct? Is it copied into the field, moved again, or constructed "in-place"?

Comment: @user3612643 You are using aggregate initialization, so the `optional` is constructed directly into the result object for the function call.